# Cannot insert json value with jooq-vertx-classic-reactive: org.jooq.JSON can not be coerced to the expected class java.lang.Object

Tags: java, json, postgresql, vert.x, jooq

I have table with 3 columns and one of them has 'json' type. When I try to insert values(with empty json, but it doesnt' matter is it empty or not, it doesn't work in any way.) then I get the error:

> java.lang.AssertionError: io.vertx.core.impl.NoStackTraceThrowable:
> Parameter at position[1] with class = [org.jooq.JSON] and value =
> ["{}"] can not be coerced to the expected class = [java.lang.Object]
> for encoding.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
  public Future<Void> saveInstances(List<Instances> instances, String tenantId) {
    return getQueryExecutor(tenantId).transaction(queryExecutor -> queryExecutor.execute(dslContext -> {
      InsertValuesStep3<InstancesRecord, UUID, JSON, String> insertValues = dslContext.insertInto(INSTANCES, INSTANCES.INSTANCE_ID,
          INSTANCES.JSON, INSTANCES.REQUEST_ID);
      instances.forEach(instance -> insertValues.values(instance.getInstanceId(), instance.getJson(), instance.getRequestId()));
      return insertValues;
    })
      .map(rows -> null));
  }
```

**getQueryExecutor(tenantId)** returns the ReactiveClassicGenericQueryExecutor object
**insatnce.getJson()** reutns org.jooq.JSON type.

**Database is PostgreSQL.**
I don't want to use any converters and etc. Documentation says that jooq supports JSON and jsonb natively but what is the problem with them here?
As well I didn't get rowMappers generated for tables that contain JSON or jsonb columns.

```
<jooq.version>3.13.2</jooq.version>
<vertx-jooq.generator.version>5.1.1</vertx-jooq.generator.version>
<vertx-jooq.classic-reactive.version>5.2.0</vertx-jooq.classic-reactive.version>
```

Got confused with that, any suggestions will be helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and solved it by adding to the pom.xml:

```
<configuration>
   <generator>
      <database>
         <forcedTypes>
            <forcedType>
               <userType>io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject</userType>
               <converter>io.github.jklingsporn.vertx.jooq.shared.postgres.JSONToJsonObjectConverter</converter>
               <expression>[column expression here]</expression>
               <types>(?i:JSON)</types>
            </forcedType>
         </forcedTypes>
      </database>
   </generator>
</configuration>
```

Replace `JSONToJsonObjectConverter` by `JSONBToJsonObjectConverter`, if you have JSONB column and specify the type for it. In expression you specify the columns for applying the specifc converter (e.g. only the column name).

This replaces the `org.jooq.JSON` type in your POJO's with `io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject`.

Be careful to choose compatible versions of `vert.x` and `vertx-jooq`.